# Ubuntu 14.04 - Wifi keeps disconnecting on Thinkpad T450S with Realtek wireless adapter

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, thinkpad, realtek

The wifi connection disconnects many times per hour. The problem only occurs at my work (not at home). Maybe there's something to configure about the wireless driver or something?

Here's the driver : `modinfo r8192ee`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192ee/r8192ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     046553152F8274C9D21FCAC
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000818Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
staging:        Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:63:E8:EF:0C:63:AB:DB:14:5F:D1:7C:AA:A9:7B:8C:69:73:45:84
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
```

**EDIT** : I think it's even less stable under 14.10

Comment: And ... nothing?

Comment: I actually gave up, I ended up buying an Intel Wireless 7265 on ebay, and it now runs perfectly smooth. For around 50 bucks, I guess that was the best workaround.

Comment: ... Not so cool ... but good deal anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem on my Lenovo Y50 (rtl8723be), where wifi would disconnect with random intervals (between 5-10 minutes)

I found this thread that matched my problems: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262957

where user Pilot6 suggests to update drivers from this repository https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new and it looks like it has drivers for your (rtl8192ee) card as well.

this stabilized the wifi connections for me at least

instructions;

```
#dependencies
sudo apt-get install git build-essential

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git /tmp/rtlwifi
cd /tmp/rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot -n
```

Comment: This is a right way, but I suggest installing it using my ppa with dkms.