# Highly unstable wifi Realteck Lenovo T450s with rtl8192ee

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, lenovo, realtek

My WiFi doesn't work on my newest Lenovo T450s. By doesn't work, I mean sometimes it will work, and then for some reason it'll stop. It'll even break the router if I insist too much on reconnecting.

I have [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598750/ubuntu-14-04-wifi-keep-disconnecting-thinkpad-t450s-realtek-wireless) everything and seen [every post](http://tutnew.com/ubuntu-14-04-wifi-keep-disconnecting-thinkpad-t450s-realtek-wireless/) on the topic.

Here's what I have:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-38-generic

~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 68:f7:28:8a:e2:b6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.2-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:61 memory:e1200000-e121ffff memory:e123e000-e123efff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: ac:e0:10:0f:4f:87
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ee driverversion=3.16.0-38-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:64 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:e1000000-e1003fff
```

which if I'm correct, means the driver used is `rtl8192ee 3.16.0-38-generic`.

Thing is, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I have read several times that there were unstabilities with the newest drivers. So I tried to downgrade/[backport](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605988/unstable-wifi-on-lenovo-t440p-using-ubuntu-14-10) to an older [kernel version](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline). Without success: I keep seeing 3.16.0-* in the grub menu.

I also tried to [disable N](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/34ln2h/t450s_ubuntu_1504_unstable_wifi/), or other encryption options, on several drivers, without success.

Answer (score 0):

Just install this driver

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi-new
make
sudo make install
```

But you will have to re-install it after each kernel upgrade.

Comment: Installation went fine, I rebooted, but the `rtlwifi` doesn't seem to be used: `sudo lshw -C network | grep driver`: `configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ee driverversion=3.16.0-38-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes`. Did I miss something?

Comment: It is used. Rtlwifi is a number of drivers, rtl8192ee is one of them. It just replaced the original one. This is a newer version from Relatek engineers. It should work much better.

Comment: I wish but it doesn't...

Comment: Do you have Windows? Does it work better? It can be a hardware problem, like bad contact in antenna. Anyway it is the best driver for this chip for now.